# Tortoise SVN and Visual Basic

Tags: svn, visual-basic

I'm about to start using Tortoise SVN with a group of VB6 projects. Some of the class modules in the projects are common to several of them, and I'm not quite sure how to save these in the repository. Does anyone know of any help available for this situation, or does anyone have any advice or suggestions to offer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SVN way to share common parts is to use **externals**.